# How to sream A Gpu stored Image using Gstream using C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu, streaming, gstreamer

I have developed an algorithm that captures frames from a camera using GPU acceleration. My goal is to stream the resulting frames using the GPU to a specific IP address, utilizing the RTP protocol to maintain the same frame rate (FPS).

I have managed to stream the results using the CPU, but during the image transfer between the GPU and CPU, I experience a significant loss of 15 FPS, resulting in lag in the streamed video.

So, here is the code with Gstream code that construct a pipline to stream over an IP adresse but I cant make it work. If any one have an idea why I would be grateful.

```
// create input for reading video directly to GPU 
videoOptions opt;
opt.width  = 1920;
opt.height = 1080;
opt.frameRate = 30;
opt.zeroCopy = false; // GPU access only for better speed

videoSource * input = videoSource::Create("csi://0", opt);
videoSource * input1 = videoSource::Create("csi://1", opt); 

if (!input) {
    std::cerr << "Error: Failed to create input stream" << std::endl;
    exit(-1);
}


// Read one frame to get resolution
uchar3* image = NULL;
uchar3* image1 = NULL;
if( !input->Capture(&image, 1000) )
{
    std::cerr << "Error: failed to capture first video frame" << std::endl;
    delete output;
    delete input;
    exit(3);
}



//initialize Gstream
gst_init(&argc, &argv);

// Create GStreamer pipeline
GstElement *pipeline, *appsrc, *queue1, *videoconvert1, *queue2, *videoconvert2, *nvvidconv, *encoder, *h264parse, *mpegtsmux, *rtpmp2tpay, *udpsink;
GstCaps *caps;

pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("video-pipeline");
appsrc = gst_element_factory_make("appsrc", "video-source");
queue1 = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "queue1");
videoconvert1 = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "video-convert1");
queue2 = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "queue2");
videoconvert2 = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "video-convert2");
nvvidconv = gst_element_factory_make("nvvidconv", "video-convert-nv");
encoder = gst_element_factory_make("nvv4l2h264enc", "video-encoder");
h264parse = gst_element_factory_make("h264parse", "h264-parse");
mpegtsmux = gst_element_factory_make("mpegtsmux", "mpegts-mux");
rtpmp2tpay = gst_element_factory_make("rtpmp2tpay", "rtp-mp2tpay");
udpsink = gst_element_factory_make("udpsink", "udp-sink");

if (!pipeline || !appsrc || !queue1 || !videoconvert1 || !queue2 || !videoconvert2 ||
!nvvidconv || !encoder || !h264parse || !mpegtsmux || !rtpmp2tpay || !udpsink) {
g_error("Failed to create elements");
return -1;
}

// Set the video format and resolution (adjust as needed)
caps = gst_caps_from_string("video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=1920, height=1080, framerate=30/1");
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(appsrc), "caps", caps, NULL);
gst_caps_unref(caps);

// Set RTP sink properties (adjust as needed)
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(udpsink), "host", "127.0.0.1", "port", 5004, NULL);

// Add elements to the pipeline
gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), appsrc, queue1, videoconvert1, queue2, videoconvert2, nvvidconv,
         encoder, h264parse, mpegtsmux, rtpmp2tpay, udpsink, NULL);


// Link elements
if (!gst_element_link_many(appsrc, queue1, videoconvert1, queue2, videoconvert2, nvvidconv,
                   encoder, h264parse, mpegtsmux, rtpmp2tpay, udpsink, NULL)) {
g_error("Failed to link elements");
return -1;
}

// Set the pipeline to playing state
gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);




// Set variabele to get the start time to calculate the FPS
double prev = (double) cv::getTickCount();
while( 1 )
{
    // capture next image
    if( !input->Capture(&image, 1000) )
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: failed to capture video frame" << std::endl;
        continue;
    }

    if( !input1->Capture(&image1, 1000) )
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: failed to capture video1 frame" << std::endl;
        continue;
    }


    // Some OpenCv processing
    cv::cuda::GpuMat frame_in(input->GetHeight(), input->GetWidth(), CV_8UC3, image);
    cv::cuda::GpuMat frame_in1(input1->GetHeight(), input1->GetWidth(), CV_8UC3, image1);
    cv::cuda::cvtColor(frame_in, frame_in, cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR);

    // Push the GPU frame to the GStreamer pipeline
    GstBuffer *buffer = gst_buffer_new_wrapped_full(
        GST_MEMORY_FLAG_READONLY, (uchar3*)frame_in.data, frame_in.step * frame_in.rows,
        0, frame_in.step * frame_in.rows, nullptr, nullptr);
    GstFlowReturn ret;
    g_signal_emit_by_name(appsrc, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);

    if (ret != GST_FLOW_OK) {
    std::cerr << "Error pushing buffer to GStreamer pipeline: " << gst_flow_get_name(ret) << std::endl;
    // You can add error handling code here, such as breaking the loop or taking appropriate action.
    }

    // Release the buffer
    gst_buffer_unref(buffer);

    // Press 'Esc' to exit the loop
    int k = cv::waitKey(5);
    if (k == 27) {
    break; // Press 'Esc' to exit the loop
    }

    // log timing to calculate FPS
    double cur = (double) cv::getTickCount();
    double delta = 1/((cur - prev) / cv::getTickFrequency());
    std::cout<<"FPS = " << delta << std::endl;
    prev=cur;


    if( !input->IsStreaming() )
        break;

    if( !input1->IsStreaming() )
        break;
}


// Clean up
gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(pipeline));

// Clean Input and output
delete input;
delete input1;

return 0;
```